# Lavaan Mediation

Tags: r

I am trying to Conduct a mediation analysis via SEM (using lavaan). The model should be specified as follows: mediator is Sexual Disgust, the predictor is Gender, and the outcome variable is Political views with regards to social views.

I am doing the code placed below and I keep on getting the error for the fit<-sem line. I am overall confused on what I am doing wrong as this is my first lavaan I have ever done.

````
modal<-'PolOri_Social ~ b*Sexual_Disgust+c*Gender~a*Gender
# indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)'

fit <- sem(model, data = Tyburdata)
summary(fit)```


'''Error in lavaan::lavaan(model = model, data = Tyburdata, model.type = "sem", : 
lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: Y M;;```
````

Comment: Your object is named modal, but in sem()  you are calling an object named model